how to verify if other build has been built successfully before deploying the release in azure devops
We have a requirement where after the QA2 Release we have to trigger a build which will do some activity in qa2 and create a build. We have to pass some parameters or change some if build fails so we cannot keep it in the normal release pipeline.
We wanted to know if there is any way to keep check so that if the build passes then only it will be allowed to be deployed to prod otherwise shouldnt allow.

Is there any gates or checks available to make this possible?

Your workflow seems a bit... Complicated :-)
Does QA2 Test build really have to be a build? Why not add it as a stage to the release pipeline that runs between QA2 and PROD?

Another option would be to create a dedicated release pipeline for the PROD environment, that gets triggered by a successful run of QA2 Test Build.

@karthik, You can use the Invoke REST API check to set a gate on the PROD stage. Fore more details, see my answer below.

@RuiJarimba we have to pass parameters if the build fails.

Sure, you can use the Gates on the "Pre-deployment conditions" of PROD stage. you just need to use the Invoke REST API check to call the REST API "Latest - Get".

Go to "Project Settings" > "Service connections" to create a Generic service connection. The values of the following two field are required.

Server URL: The prefix of the HTTP URL of the API. For example, https://dev.azure.com/{orgName}. The {orgName} is the actual name of your Azure DevOps organization.
Service connection name: A custom name of the service connection.



On the "Pre-deployment conditions" of PROD stage, enable Gates and add the Invoke REST API check with below configurations.

Connection type: Generic

Generic service connection: Name of the Generic service connection create previously.

Method: GET

Headers (json):
{
  "Content-Type":"application/json", 
  "Authorization": "Bearer $(system.AccessToken)"
}


URL suffix and parameters: /{projName}/_apis/build/latest/{definitionId}?api-version=7.0-preview.1
The {projName} is the actual name of your project, and the {definitionId} is the definition ID of the build pipeline (QA2 Test Build).

Advanced > Completion event: ApiResponse

Advanced > Success criteria: eq(root['result'], 'succeeded')






